# powershell search string if it is at two places in file

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I have following two lines in my Input file.

Sample Input file ( name of file - `file.txt`)

```
String1   value   'string2'
..
..
..
Call  string1
```

Desired output :

```
File.txt. ( i.e. Name of file )
```

Basically i want names of file - if it contains these two lines

```
1) string1 value 'string2' 
 2) CALL string1
```

i.e. `string1`  comes before `'Value 'string2'`
and   'string1' comes after `'CALL'`

1) and 2) above are two different lines and there could be many lines in between.

P.S. a) i am searching for 'string2' . 'string1' could be any 8 characters. I do not know 'string1'

Could there be someway where I can store 'String1' if it comes before `'Value 'String2''`  and then search the rest of notepad file for `'String1'` (match it if it is in pattern `CALL STRING1`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$foundCall = $false
$string1 = $null

gc "C:\path\to\file.txt" | % {
  if ($_ -match "^(.{8}) value 'string2'") {
    $string1 = $matches[1]
  } elseif ($string1 -ne $null) {
    if ($_ -match "CALL $string1") { $foundCall = $true }
  }
}

if ($foundCall) { $file.Name }
```